# CSS of landingspage keeps getting overwritten?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, templates, background

I have a custom page template that I use as landingspage. In this template I defined a specific image as background.

In my specific template I added this css in the page itself:

```html
<body background="frank4.jpg" style="background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment:fixed;background-position:center ; overflow:hidden;">
```

But this keeps getting overwritten by my general CSS. Why, how do I change it back?

Site is [www.frankgalan.be](http://www.frankgalan.be)

It used to work fine this way but for some reason it does not anymore.

Comment: set your background using CSS after your general CSS file is loaded

Comment: See [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and work out what is overriding what.

Comment: Also -- `background="frank4.jpg"` is not a valid HTML attribute or CSS tag.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with inline background property setting **!important** to override previous calls of same rule:

```
<body style="background: url('frank4.jpg') no-repeat center top fixed !important; overflow: hidden;">
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The `!important` qualifier is not necessary here, I don't think.

Comment: That's true, I have put that in case that it gets overridden from a previous **!important** rule.